# Parsing Deeply Nested Python Dictionary/Tuple

Tags: python

I'm trying to parse/loop through a deeply nested dictionary/tuple such as this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

movies = {
    'in_bruges': {
        'display': 'In Bruges',
        'actors': {
            'Colin Farrel': {
                'age': '99',
                'height': '160'
            },
            'Brendan Gleeson': {
                'age': '88',
                'height': '158'
            }
            # many more...
        }
    },
    'fargo': {
        'display': 'Fargo',
        'actors': {
            'William H. Macy': {
                'age': '109',
                'height': '120'
            },
            'Steve Buscemi': {
                'age': '11',
                'height': '118'
            }
            # many more...
        }
    }
    # many more...
}
```

I can access individual fields just fine:

```
print(movies['in_bruges']['actors']['Brendan Gleeson']['age']);
88
```

But I'm having a hard time looping through the whole thing. This is what I have so far...

```
for movie, val in movies.iteritems():
    print movie
    for v in val.values():
        print v
        for x in v.values():  # <-- BREAKS HERE
            print x
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'
```

I understand why it's breaking... just not sure how to fix it. Also, and probably more importantly, **is there a better way to do this**? This is a mix of a dictionary and a tuple (correct me if I'm wrong). Should I structure it differently? Or use a different method altogether? I'd rather not read it in from a csv or text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all your values are dictionaries; some are strings:

```
# ...
'in_bruges': {
    'display': 'In Bruges',
    'actors': {
        # ...
```

That's a string and a dictionary. You'll have to vary your handling:

```
for movie, val in movies.iteritems():
    print movie
    for v in val.values():
        if hasattr(v, 'values'):
            for x in v.values():
                print x
        else:
            print v
```

Here I used *ducktyping*; checking for a method I want to use, rather than a type; if it is present we assume it can be treated as a dictionary. You could also use `isinstance(v, dict)` but the above is more flexible as it allows anything with the right method to be treated the same.

You could use recursion to handle arbitrary values at any depth:

```
def print_dictionary(d, indent=0):
    try:
        for k, v in d.iteritems():
            print (indent * '  '), k, '->'
            print_dictionary(v, indent + 1)
    except AttributeError:
        print (indent * '  '), d
```

Here I used exception handling; if the `dict.iteritems()` method isn't present an `AttributeError` is raised. This technique is called *Look Before You Leap*.

With your demo dictionary this outputs:

```
>>> print_dictionary(movies)
 fargo ->
   actors ->
     William H. Macy ->
       age ->
         109
       height ->
         120
     Steve Buscemi ->
       age ->
         11
       height ->
         118
   display ->
     Fargo
 in_bruges ->
   actors ->
     Brendan Gleeson ->
       age ->
         88
       height ->
         158
     Colin Farrel ->
       age ->
         99
       height ->
         160
   display ->
     In Bruges
```

Comment: Wow this is excellent! Works perfectly. Thanks so much for the thoughtful explanation, Martijn. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the check of type before access to values/value:

```
isinstance(v, dict)
```

or

```
isinstance(v, basestring)
```

And the code will be:

```
for movie, val in movies.iteritems():
    print movie
    for v in val.values():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            for x in v.values():
                print x
        elif isinstance(v, basestring):
            print v
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# for all movies
for movie, movie_details in movies.iteritems(): 
    print movie
    display = movie_details['display']
    print display

    # for all actors in this movie
    for actor,actor_details in movie_details['actors'].iteritems():
        print actor
        print actor_details['age']
        print actor_details['height']
```